# How many hematopeietic stem cells (in percentage) does the bone marrow contains?

Tags: hematology, stem-cells

I've found out that the body marrow of an adult weights about 5% of it's total weight. How much (%) of the bone marrow consists of hematopeietic stem cells and how much consists of other non-hematopoietic cells, i. e. "stroma" (%) ? I've also found that in adults, ~70% of bone marrow consists of adipocite cells.

Comment: What research have you done to try to find the answer? **Homework questions** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). "*Homework*" is interpreted to mean any academic or other assignment, test preparation, or task given in relation to a class, educational setting, or self-learning.

Comment: Im not a biology student. My baby girl was diagnosed with AML - M5a (FAB) and I am trying to understand better What's going on in her bone marrow and how the hematopoesis works in a healthy organism. The doctors explains it, but they don't go so deep. It helps me psihologicaly to understand better the underlying mechanisms.

Comment: In the bone marrow usually, the amount of stem cells is very low less than 99% of cells. You can check that on the Williams haematology book. It shouldn't be hard to find online.